# Show that $f(x, y) = \frac{x^3y−xy^3}{x^2+y^2}$ is continuous at $(0,0)$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Let
>   $$f(x, y) =\begin{cases} \dfrac{x^3y−xy^3}{x^2+y^2},& \text{if }(x,y)\neq(0,0)\\
> 0,& \text{if } (x,y) = (0,0).\end{cases}$$
>   Show $f$ is continuous at $(0, 0)$. (Hint: Use the Squeeze Theorem.)

Also compute ∂x f(x, y) and ∂y f(x, y) for (x, y) not = (0, 0) using derivative rules.

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2):

$x^3y - xy^3 = (xy)(x^2 - y^2)$
and $|x^2 - y^2| \leq (x^2 + y^2)$

$0\leq |f(x,y)| \leq |xy|$

Comment: The approach I had had (y=kx) works to show that a limit does not exist.  But, I was rewriting when you posted nearly exactly what I was thinking.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**

Note that we can write

$$\begin{align}
\left|\frac{x^3y-xy^3}{x^2+y^2}\right|&= |xy|\,\left|\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}\right|\\\\
&\le |xy|
\end{align}$$

Comment: where do i go from there?

Comment: what would i use as the function less than f(x,y)

Comment: $0\le|f(x,y)|\le |xy|$